# Disabling extensions on envoy proxy

Tags: envoyproxy

According to the documentation, there is flag `--disable-extensions <extension list>` where you can specify a list of extensions that need to be disabled.

I want to disable this extension for e.g. https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/clusters/aggregate/v3/cluster.proto#extensions-clusters-aggregate-v3-clusterconfig

I tried running this way

`envoy --disable-extensions envoy.clusters.aggregate` as well as

`envoy --disable-extensions clusters.envoy.clusters.aggregate`

I get this error

```
[2020-11-18 05:46:55.203][1][warning][misc] failed to disable invalid extension name 'clusters.envoy.clusters.aggregate'
```

in both cases

I have the following questions:

1. What's the correct way to identify the extension name so that it can be passed as a parameter here?
2. How can I list all the extensions that are enabled/disabled?
3. After disabling the extensions, what's the best way to test if it's disabled?

Comment: eg. `envoy.grpc_credentials/envoy.grpc_credentials.file_based_metadata` according to https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/operations/cli#cmdoption-disable-extensions

Comment: starting envoy without command line options will print the extensions enabled